# Real bash line count

Tags: bash, wc

I'm parsing a temp file whose lines would like removed so I run: `tr '\n' ' ' < temp > temp2`. Now when I `wc -l temp2` it is returning 0 lines instead of 1 which was unexpected for me.

After checking the manual, `wc -l` counts just the newlines and not the lines. Its behaviour is fine but might be problematic if you don't know if the last line of a file contains a line feed.

Is there any tool or workaround that count lines even if they have no linefeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

will work fine without the trailing newline.

Comment: While my situation is explained by John Kugelman's answer, this addresses the original broad question since the file might not be a text file

Answer (score 3):

UNIX text files [must always have a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline). Without it, many tools will fail to process the last line, exactly as you are seeing. Rather than looking for a tool that can handle it I'd fix the error in your file.

```
{ tr '\n' ' ' < temp && echo; } > temp2
```

Comment: Thank you very much John but then this makes me wonder: Shouldn't the redirection have created the trailing newline, in order to make a valid file ?

Comment: @carlosmarti: redirection is not limited to text files. `wc`, on the other hand, is.